# Why won't my tty1 let me login?

Tags: login, tty

I have a raspberry pi 400, and earlier this week I was attempting to change some settings. When my computer rebooted, It showed the tty1 and asked for my login and password. I know both of these by heart, but when I typed it in, it said `Login incorrect` and asked again. After repeating this what feels like hundreds of times daily, adding things like the pi@ in front of my user, or using different and older passwords and usernames, but it didn't work. I'm all out of options and locked out of my computer. Can anyone help?

(P.s. my password doesn't show up when I typed it, but I think that's supposed to happen)

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu or Raspbian?

Comment: it asks for a user name then a password do you know your username

Comment: @will I think it is a Raspbian, but I don't know for sure.